# Adding values in a list if they are the same, with a twist

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have a question (python) regarding adding values in a list if they share the same key in a first list. So for example we have:

```
lst1 = [A, A, B, A, C, D]
lst2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

What I would like to know is how I can add the numbers in lst2 if the strings in lst1 are the sane. The end result would thus be:

```
new_lst1 = [A, B, A, C, D]
new_lst2 = [3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

where

```
new_lst2[0] = 1+2
```

So values only get added when the are next to each other.

To make it more complicated, it should also be possible if we have this example:

```
lst3 = [A, A, A, B, B, A, A]
lst4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

for which the result has to be:

```
new_lst3 = [A, B, A]
new_lst4 = [6, 9, 13]
```

where
`new_lst4[0] = 1 + 2 + 3`, `new_lst4[1] = 4 + 5`, and `new_lst4[2] = 6 + 7`.

Thank you in advance!

for a bit of background:
I wrote a code that searches in Dutch online underground models and returns the data of the underground of a specific input location.

The data is made up of layers:
Layer1, Name: "BXz1", top_layer, bottom_layer, transitivity
Layer2, Name: "BXz2", top_layer, bottom_layer, transitivity
Layer3, Name: "KRz1", top_layer, bottom_layer, transitivity

etc..

BXz1 and BXz2 are the same main layer however different sublayers. In terms of transitivity I would like to combine them if they are next to each other.
so in that way i would get:
Layer1+2, Name: BX, top_layer1, bottom_layer2, combined transitivity
Layer3, Name: "KRz1", top_layer, bottom_layer, transitivity

Comment: Which language? Add the appropriate tags to your question. Also please show what you have tried so far and describe where you are getting stuck; StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: thank you for the heads-up, in python (edited the question for clarity)

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  It seems like you've got yourself a weird data format,  what makes that first list?

Comment: see the added edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not allowed to use libraries, you could do it with a simple loop using zip() to pair up the keys and values.

```
lst3 = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"]
lst4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

new_lst3,new_lst4 = lst3[:1],[0] # initialize with first key
for k,n in zip(lst3,lst4):       # pair up keys and numbers
    if new_lst3[-1] != k:        # add new items if key changed
        new_lst3.append(k)
        new_lst4.append(0)
    new_lst4[-1] += n            # tally for current key
    
print(new_lst3) # ['A', 'B', 'A']
print(new_lst4) # [6, 9, 13]
```

If you're okay with libraries, groupby from itertools combined with an iterator on the keys will allow you to express it more concisely:

```
from itertools import groupby

tally = ((k,sum(n)) for i3 in [iter(lst3)] 
         for k,n in groupby(lst4,lambda _:next(i3)))
new_lst3,new_lst4 = map(list,zip(*tally))
```

Comment: I have to admit, your groupby implementation is very clever, if hard to read. It's also faster than mine, by about 25% (as benchmarked on one-million-element lists). Your no-library solution is actually the fastest, taking about half as long as my implementation on that same benchmark. To my surprise, though, the differences in memory use are quite small, the fastest saving only about 10% memory.

Answer (score 2):

The `itertools.groupby` function in the standard library provides the base functionality you need. It's then a matter of giving it the right key and tallying the count in each group.

Here's my implementation:

```
from itertools import groupby

def tally_by_group(keys, counts):
    groups = groupby(zip(keys, counts), key=lambda x: x[0])
    tallies = [
        (key, sum(count for _, count in group))
        for key, group in groups
    ]
    return tuple(list(l) for l in zip(*tallies))
```

Code explanation:

- my first `zip()` creates (key, count) tuples from the two lists,
- the `groupby` groups them by the first element of each tuple, i.e., by the key,
- then I construct a list of (key, sum(count)) into `tallies`,
- and finally unpack that back into two lists for the results.

Tests with your examples:

```
lst1 = ["A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D"]
lst2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

l1m, l2m = tally_by_group(lst1, lst2)
print(l1m)
print(l2m)
```

outputs:

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D']
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And

```
lst3 = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"]
lst4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

l3m, l4m = tally_by_group(lst3, lst4)
print(l3m)
print(l4m)
```

outputs:

```
['A', 'B', 'A']
[6, 9, 13]
```

Comment: I thought Pandas might make this more straightforward, but [it really doesn't](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5494).